# Using LINQ to count values in a multiple join

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

How do I count by description in my linq query below?

I can select, group etc but unable to count?

```
plant = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
         join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
         where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
         join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
         where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
         join p in db.PLANT on i.CODE equals p.CODE      
         select p.DESCRIPTION.Count())
```

Thanks for your help as always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a count on the column instead of the result. Try moving the count:

```
  var plant = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
     join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
     where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
     join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
     where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
     join p in db.PLANT on i.CODE equals p.CODE      
     select p.DESCRIPTION).Count();
```

You probably can get rid of the `where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER` as well as it is already taken care of in the join, so your query would become:

```
  var plant = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
     join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
     where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
     join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
     join p in db.PLANT on i.CODE equals p.CODE      
     select p.DESCRIPTION).Count();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Jao, I see my mistake, but when I move the count to the result I get the following error  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CallistoWebApp.Models.PLANT>'

Comment: It returns an Int, which is indeed not a IEnumerable<CallistoWebApp.Models.PLANT>. You might need to change that in your controller and view .

Comment: I see, so in my viewmodel where I have created several IEnumerable collections for each of my tables I should use a different collection instead of IEnumerable?  Do you have a suggestion which would be best to get the results I am after?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jao, I created an int value in my viewmodel and queried the results in the controller, then sent the count to my view.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
plant = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
     join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
     where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
     join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
     where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
     join p in db.PLANT on i.CODE equals p.CODE      
     select p.DESCRIPTION).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need wrap the query in parentheses to perform the `Count` on the entire query result.

```
plant = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
         join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
         where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
         join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
         where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
         join p in db.PLANT on i.CODE equals p.CODE      
         select p.DESCRIPTION).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var plant = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
     join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
     where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
     join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
     where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
     join p in db.PLANT on i.CODE equals p.CODE      
     select p.DESCRIPTION).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 plant = (from c in db.CLIENTDETAILS
 join l in db.LOCATIONS on c.CLIENTNUMBER equals l.CLIENTNUMBER
 where c.CLIENTNUMBER == clientNumber
 join i in db.ITEMDETAILS on l.LOCNUMBER equals i.LOCNUMBER
 where i.LOCNUMBER == l.LOCNUMBER
 join p in db.PLANT on i.CODE equals p.CODE      
 select p.DESCRIPTION).Count();
```